# Customize sectioned table view

Tags: uitableview, xcode4.5

I have an sectioned Uitableview where as for each section i have a Question(UILabel) with 5 Uibuttons as radiobuttons .
  I will get number of radoibuttons dynamically .when i select one radiobutton Iam getting the state highlighted but if i click another radiobutton in that section am getting two radiobuttons as highlighted.

But it is notthe correct way i want to show all radiobuttons in that section must be unselected ad the selected must be highlighted .how can i do this

this is my code when radiobutton clicks

```
-(IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender{


    NSMutableArray *arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)
                              [[sender superview] superview]];


    NSLog(@"The section  is %d",  indexPath.section);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    int n=[cellSection count]-3;
    int m=[cellSection count]-1;
    NSString *questionId=[[cellSection objectAtIndex:m-1]objectForKey:@"QId"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in selectedOptionandQIdArray) {

        NSString *str=[dict valueForKey:@"QId"];
        if(str==NULL)
        {

        }
        else{

        [arr1 addObject:str];
        }

    }

    BOOL isTheObjectThere = [arr1 containsObject:questionId];

        if(isTheObjectThere==YES)
    {
         NSInteger Aindex=[arr1 indexOfObject:questionId];
        if(NSNotFound != Aindex) 
        {
            NSLog(@" found");
            [selectedOptionandQIdArray removeObjectAtIndex:Aindex];
        }


    }

     NSLog(@"%d",sender.tag);

    int tagID=[sender tag];


    int itemtoAdd=[sender tag];

    NSString *xWrapped=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"raid%d",itemtoAdd];

    NSMutableDictionary *hk=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [hk setObject:xWrapped forKey:@"Ans"];
    [hk setObject:questionId forKey:@"QId"];
    [hk setObject:@"" forKey:@"TestOption"];


    [selectedOptionandQIdArray addObject:hk];
    NSMutableArray *radioButtonsinaSection=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if(n==5)
    {
        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"];

        NSLog(@"%d",tagID);


       UIButton  *btnTemp1 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:11];
        UIButton  *btnTemp2 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:12];
        UIButton  *btnTemp3 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:13];
        UIButton *btnTemp4=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:14];
        UIButton *btnTemp5=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:15];
      [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp1];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp2];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp3];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp4];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp5];

       }

        [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-On.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];         




 for(int i=0;i<[radioButtonsinaSection count];i++){


    [[radioButtonsinaSection objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }





}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it....

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int buttonTag = indexPath.row + 200;
//NSLog(@"%i",buttonTag);
UIButton *tempBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag];
[tempBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox_check.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];     
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
int buttonTag = indexPath.row + 200;
NSLog(@"%i",buttonTag);
UIButton *tempBtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag];
[tempBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
}
```